# EndInvoke retrieves nothing

Tags: vb.net, begininvoke

I have a UI method that needs to be called on the UI thread.
Therefore I call it via a `BeginInvoke` on the form control that owns it, from another thread:

```
Dim currProjForm As Form_Project_Contaner = HomeForm.GetActiveProject()
Dim asyncOpDlg As [Delegate] = New OpenDocForReportDelegate(AddressOf currProjForm.OpenDocForReport)
currProjForm.BeginInvoke(asyncOpDlg, documentId, revisionId, exportProvider)
```

That method could throw an exception, so I decided to wrap its code in a `Try...Catch` block and return the exception object so I can retrieve it with an `EndInvoke`:

```
Public Function OpenDocForReport(ByVal documentId As Int32,
                                 ByVal revisionId As Int32,
                                 ByVal exportProvider As IExportProvider) As Exception

    Try
        '...statements...
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return ex
    End Try
    Return Nothing

End Function
```

and

```
Dim asyncOpToken As IAsyncResult = currProjForm.BeginInvoke(asyncOpDlg, documentId, revisionId, exportProvider)
Dim asyncOpRet = currProjForm.EndInvoke(asyncOpToken)
```

The fact is that I get `Nothing` (`null`) even if an exception was thrown and correctly returned (seen in debugger) by the UI method.

Any help on that?
(Don't mind about VB or C#, I have no problems understanding both)

Comment: Please show the declaration for OpenDocForReportDelegate

Comment: Are the `BeginInvoke` and `EndInvoke` calls back to back?  Why not just use `Invoke`?

Comment: @JonSkeet has the right answer! Delegate was of an old version (method has been modified after writing it) and didn't return Exception!

Comment: @BenVoigt Actually I was convinced that I needed BeginInvoke to make the call execute in the UI thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET delegate types are invariant, but variance does apply when converting from a method group to a delegate type.

In particular, the return type of the actual method can be a subclass of the return type contractually promised by the delegate type, and all method types are compatible with a delegate type that returns `void`.  In such a case, what the caller receives depends on the formal return type of the delegate, not the bound method.  This hardly matters with `EndInvoke`, which casts all results as object anyway, unless the delegate is declared to return `void`, in which case `EndInvoke` returns `null`.

Comment: Accepting this. Actually @JonSkeet gave me the first right answer, but he only leaved a comment.